# Block multiple request on website through Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver

How to block IPs with multiple requests within short period of time (minutes) by Nginx configuration (configured in Ubuntu)?

Comment: There is a module to limit the request rate which might help. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RichardSmith is there any other way?